# Tabular Horizontal Line Stops

Tags: tables

I am using Tabular to make a simple table. For three columns, my table displayed fine. When I added a fourth column, the horizontal lines stopped reaching all the way across my table. I also have a little bit of horizontal line that sticks out on the left side of the table. What went wrong with my table?

[image]

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill } }  | l | c | c |  c  || }
  \hline 
  \textbf{GENE} &   \textbf{Allele of interest} &  \textbf{Outcomes}   &   \textbf{Dominance}  \\
  \hline \hline  
  MAOA  & 2.5, 3, 5     & Agression     &  Recessive, Sex-selective \\  \hline
  DAT1      & 10R       &  ADHD         & hz. disadvantage          \\  \hline
  DRD4  & 7R        & ADHD      &  -                        \\  \hline
  5-HTT     & 14 (s)    & Negative Thoughts, Fear  & Dominant           \\ \hline
  TRI   & S         & Depression        & Codominant                \\  \hline
  DRD2  & A         & Alcoholism        & Dominant                  \\ \hline
  DRD5  & 148   & ADHD          &  -                        \\  \hline
  S000005 & A       & Stress            & -                         \\ \hline
  S000006 & T       & ADHD          & -                         \\ \hline
  MAOCA1 & 115+     & Alcoholism        & Sex selective             \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: It appears to me, as if the lines are just set to `.75\textwidth`, while the actual table is much wider. Do you really need this constrain?

Comment: Thanks! The .75\textwidth constraint was not needed. I see that removing that makes the lines go all the way across. But the code below looks much better! I have used LaTex for math homework for years, but am only just starting to use it for papers so the formatting is all new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may, I would recommend to redesign the complete table. The code posted above is much to wide.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % for demo that the table fits into the page limits
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{the caption}
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.5cm}ll}
    \toprule 
    \textbf{GENE} & \textbf{Allele of interest} & \textbf{Outcomes} & \textbf{Dominance} \\
    \midrule  
    MAOA    & 2.5, 3, 5 & Agression               & Recessive, Sex-selective \\
    DAT1    & 10R       & ADHD                    & hz.\ disadvantage \\
    DRD4    & 7R        & ADHD                    & - \\
    5-HTT   & 14 (s)    & Negative Thoughts, Fear & Dominant \\
    TRI     & S         & Depression              & Codominant \\
    DRD2    & A         & Alcoholism              & Dominant \\
    DRD5    & 148       & ADHD                    & - \\
    S000005 & A         & Stress                  & - \\
    S000006 & T         & ADHD                    & - \\
    MAOCA1  & 115+      & Alcoholism              & Sex selective \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The problem with your table was that the given width of `0.75\textwidth` was exceeded by the tables content. The `\hlines` stopped, where you wanted them to stop, but the text didn't. You will have to reduce the columns width using `p{}`-columns or use an `tabularx` instead of the `tabular*`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the  horizontal line that sticks out on the left side of the table, just you need to use only one `|` not two of them `||`

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill } }  | l | c | c |  c  || }
```

Thus your code should looks like instead:

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill } }  | l | c | c |  c  | }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please do not post only fragments of code but provide a working example, with a screen shot